# What is the purpose of {.$DEFINE VAR} instead of {$DEFINE VAR} in Delphi

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, compiler-directives

What is the difference in Delphi between using {.$DEFINE VAR} and {$DEFINE VAR} compiler directives ?

Comment: It's an idiom for configuration files. All possible defines are listed with dot turning it into a comment (no effect). Remove dots where you need an option and you have "flipped a switch"

Comment: Have a look at `FastMM4Options.inc` if you have Fast MM installed. It is full of these!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code originally had a `{$DEFINE VAR}` statement in it, then a period was added to turn the statement into a plain ordinary comment without removing the statement, presumably so it can be restored at a later time.

`{$...}` is a precompiler directive.

`{...}` that does not start with `{$` is a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Think of the first one as a commented version (one that the compiler will ignore) of the second one.